# Load URL/URI from NFC tag automatically

Tags: xiaomi, nfc, url

I have a Redmi Note 8 Pro which can read NFC tags, and I wrote an NFC tag with a custom URI for an app (Obsidian). The custom URI makes the app to open and write something inside it.

The "problem" I have is that when I read the NFC tag, a panel pops up and I have to manually click it in order to "load" the URI, it's not done automatically by just approaching the NFC tag with the phone.

Is it possible to somehow automatically load the URI by approaching the phone to the NFC tag? Or is this a security measure of some kind to prevent loading malicious URIs?

Comment: I think you already got the point, this is for security reasons. As you never know what an NFC tag contains and an URL could start an operation on a web site you are logged in.

Comment: But you could use a workaround: don't write an URL to the tag, just use it as it is and use a programmable app like tasker. Create a script to open the URL you had programmed. As trigger for this script use that a specific tag (identified e.g. by it's ID) is read via NFC.